# how to use boundary with str_detect (tidyr package)

Tags: r, stringr

Here is some data.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(sentences)
```

I want to identify all sentences with the word "her." But this, of course, also returns sentences with words like "there" and "here."

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(sentences, "her"))
# A tibble: 43 x 1
   sentences                                    
   <chr>                                        
 1 The boy was there when the sun rose.         
 2 Help the woman get back to her feet.         
 3 What joy there is in living.                 
 4 There are more than two factors here.        
 5 Cats and dogs each hate the other.           
 6 The wharf could be seen at the farther shore.
 7 The tiny girl took off her hat.              
 8 Write a fond note to the friend you cherish. 
 9 There was a sound of dry leaves outside.     
10 Add the column and put the sum here.
```

The documentation for `stringr::str_detect` says, "Match character, word, line and sentence boundaries with `boundary()`." I can't figure out how to do this, nor can I find an example anywhere. All of the documentation examples involve the `str_split` or `str_count` functions.

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677876/word-boundaries-in-str-detect-function-in-r), but I would specifically like to understand how to use the `stringr::boundary` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the word boundary (`\\b`) at the start and end to avoid any partial matches

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(sentences, "\\bher\\b"))
#                             sentences
#1 Help the woman get back to her feet.
#2      The tiny girl took off her hat.
```

Or use `boundary` to wrap

```
df %>%
      filter(str_detect(sentences, boundary("her")))
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a very good solution. Was I totally off-base in thinking `stringr::boundary` offered a way to solve this?

Comment: @JohnJ. In the documentation, it says to. wrap with `boundary` `words <- c("These are   some words.");
str_count(words, boundary("word"))` or `str_detect(words, boundary("word"))#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @akrun Even though the question is 3 years old, I‘d like to understand the usage of boundary as well. The documentation of boundary doesn‘t show a clear way of using it together with str_detect and your code actually throws an error (which might be due to a change in the function behaviour somce 3 years have past.

Comment: E.g. consider a sinple example `x <- c('ohno', 'hello no.')` where I want to detect the word 'no', which of course can be done with the backslash version \\b, but how could it be done with boundary?

Comment: @deschen i think the `stringr:::check_bool` may be triggering the `stop_input_type` in the new version